# FFmpegAudio and discord.py, speeding up track

Tags: python, discord.py, pyffmpeg

I'm depeloving a discord.py bot, that has some features about music too.
I use FFmpegAudio to reproduce audio, and i'm confused about how to use FFmpeg effects/filter in d.py library, in my case i need to speedup the song, like x2, x10, x0.5 something like that. Or bass boost, and other effects. But how to implement FFmpeg in d.py(rewrite)?
For example for speedup a song i found on internet that i can use the `atmepo` argument.
How to use it in my bot?
thank you for your replys!

Comment: Hi, did you get any answer? If yes, please post it.. I will appreciate that
Thank you!